# SQL function to replace many characters in a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, replace

What would be an efficient way in SQL Server to change many bad characters in a string using a function?

For the time being I use:
update my_table

```
UPDATE dbo.my_table
SET [Description] = REPLACE([Description], '¿', N'A')
UPDATE dbo.my_table
SET [Description] = REPLACE([Description], '!', N'B')
```

I have many of those replacements. I would welcome something like:

```
dbo.function_replace_all_bad_characters(string)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TSQL doesn't support regexes so you will need multiple replaces. However, rather than multiple updates you can join the REPLACES into one update statement, for example

```
UPDATE dbo.my_table
SET [Description] = REPLACE(REPLACE([Description], '¿', N'A'), '!', N'B')
```

You could define your own function like so

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.function_replace_all_bad_characters(@str NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
    RETURN REPLACE(REPLACE(@str, '¿', N'A'), '!', N'B')
```

And use the function like so

```
UPDATE dbo.my_table
SET [Description] = dbo.function_replace_all_bad_characters([Description])
```

Comment: I don't believe there is a limit.